# ruby on rails rending two forms inside a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two modals on one page. When clicked on button `Add Providers` one modal should pop up for that. When I clicked on `Add Hospital` another modal should pop up. However, no matter which button I clicked on only the modal for 'Providers' showed up? No idea why.
Modal 1 is happening from the render partial `provider_access_modal` and the second is supposeed to happen at rendering the partial `sites_access_modal`

```
    <%= render :partial => 'provider_access_modal' %> ##Modal 1
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/side_menu' %>
    <div id="profiles" class="container-main">
        <%= render :partial => 'patients/top_bar' %>
        <div class="top-space"></div>
        <div class="flash">
            <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
                <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
            <%- end -%>
        </div>

        <div class="content-container your-sites">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="icon-circle"><div class="icon"><%= image_tag "my-providers-2x.png" %></div></div>
                <div class="title">Your Providers</div>
                <div class="button-wrapper">
                    <%= button_tag "Add Provider", class:"add-button", id: 'add-provider-modal' %>
                    <div class="push"></div>
                </div><!--button-wrapper-->
            </div><!--header-->
            <div class="body">
                    <div class="no-records">
                        <%= image_tag "icon-no-records", class: "image" %>
                        <div class="text">You have no providers.</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <%= render :partial => 'sites_access_modal' %> ##Modal 2
        <div class="content-container your-sites">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="icon-circle"><div class="icon"><%= image_tag "hospitalizations-icon-2x.png" %></div></div>
                <div class="title">Your Hospitals</div> 
                <div class="button-wrapper">

                    <%= button_tag "Add Hospital", class:"add-button", id: 'add-site-modal' %>
                    <div class="push"></div>
                </div><!--button-wrapper-->
            </div><!--header-->
            <div class="body">
                <% if @active_memberships.count > 0 %>
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Hospital Name</th>
                          <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <% @active_memberships.each do |membership| %>
                          <tr>
                            <td><%= membership.site.name %></td>
                            <td>
                                <%= link_to patient_remove_membership_path(id: current_user.id, membership_id: membership.id), method: :put, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to leave this site?'}, class: "btn" do %>Leave Hospital<% end %>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        <% end %>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                <% else %>
                    <div class="no-records">
                        <%= image_tag "icon-no-records", class: "image" %>
                        <div class="text">You have no sites.</div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Here is my provider-select.js code

```
function providerSearch(input) {
  if (input.val()) {
    var params = {
      "provider_search": {
        "query": input.val()
      }
    }
    $.post("/providers/search", params, function(data, status) {
      $(".auto-complete-modal-list .content").html(data)
      if (data.length == 0) {
        var notFound = $('<div>', {
          'text': 'No provider found, please invite a provider below',
          'class': 'item'
        });
        $(".auto-complete-modal-list .content").empty().append(notFound)
      }
    }, "html");
  } else {
    $(".auto-complete-modal-list .content").empty()
  }
}

function providerSelection(event) {
  let targetProvider = null;
  if ($(event.target).is('button')) {
    targetProvider = $(event.target);
  }
  if (targetProvider != null) {
    let providerEmail = targetProvider.closest('.item').data("email")
    let providerName = targetProvider.closest('.item').data("name")
    $('#provider-selection .item').removeAttr('style').find('button').text("Select");
    targetProvider.text("Selected")
    targetProvider.closest('.item').css({
      "background-color": "rgb(86, 116, 204, .8)"
    })
    $("#invite-label").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).text(`You are inviting ${providerName} to sign this document`).fadeIn(100);
    });
    $('#invite_email').val(providerEmail)
  }
}
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#provider-select .input-search").on("keyup", function(e) {
    providerSearch($(this));
  });
  $("#provider-selection").on("click", function(e) {
    providerSelection(e);
  });
  $('#invite_email').blur(function() {
    let cantFindText = "Can't find your provider? Invite them via email below"
    if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
      if ($('label').text() != cantFindText) {
        $("#invite-label").fadeOut(function() {
          $(this).text(cantFindText).fadeIn(40);
        });
      }
    }
  });
  // for add provider access
  $('#add-provider-modal').click(function(){
    $('#modal').show()
  })
});
```

And then here is my site-select.js code

```
function siteSearch(input) {
  if (input.val()) {
    var params = {
      "sites_search": {
        "query": input.val()
      }
    }
    $.post("/sites/search", params, function(data, status) {
      $(".auto-complete-modal-list .content").html(data)
      if (data.length == 0) {
        var notFound = $('<div>', {
          'text': 'No sites found',
          'class': 'item'
        });
        $(".auto-complete-modal-list .content").empty().append(notFound)
      }
    }, "html");
  } else {
    $(".auto-complete-modal-list .content").empty()
  }
}

function siteSelection(event) {
  let targetSite = null;
  if ($(event.target).is('button')) {
    targetSite = $(event.target);
  }
  if (targetSite != null) {
    let siteId = targetSite.closest('.item').data("id")
    $('#site-selection .item').removeAttr('style').find('button').text("Add");
    targetSite.text("Added")
    targetSite.closest('.item').css({
      "background-color": "rgb(86, 116, 204, .8)"
    })
 }
}
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#site-select .input-search").on("keyup", function(e) {
    siteSearch($(this));
  });
  $("#site-selection").on("click", function(e) {
    siteSelection(e);
  });
  $('#add-site-modal').click(function(){
    $('#modal').show()
  })
});
```

Comment: Maybe you have the same modal ids inside partials? Also, move modals rendering to the end of your page, it is bad idea to render them in the middle of <body>, wrapped in other tags

Comment: No They have different ids. I also moved them to the end of the page and still the same results

Comment: Do you open modals with some custom js? If yes, add it to the question. Also add modal's code. Do you have any errors in js console?

Comment: yes the modals are open with some custom js. I have listed both the modal codes above. I have no errors in the js console in the browser. @Vasilisa

Answer (score 1):

In both of your JavaScript snippets I can see the line

```
$('#modal').show();
```

There is:

```
  $('#add-provider-modal').click(function(){
    $('#modal').show()
  })
```

and

```
  $('#add-site-modal').click(function(){
    $('#modal').show()
  })
```

So when you click your Add Provider Modal or Add Site Model buttons, the same model, with the id "modal", will show.

In the code you have supplied I can't find an element with the ID of "modal" so it must lie within your partials that you have not provided. I would recommend changing the partials to give them different IDs for the different modals and then updating your click handlers to open the correct one at the correct time.